# Automated way to check R package for anything malicious or suspicious?

Tags: r, devtools, r-package, cran

I've found myself perusing some obscure parts of github and finding some real gems written in R. However, given some packages have zero vetting (unlike those on CRAN), I am a little uneasy about installing and using them (i.e. `devtools::install_github("user/repo")`)

One way to address the issue could be to write a function that reads an R package as text, and flags anything suspicious. An extremely crude version look like:

e.g.

```
flag_sus <- function(r_file) {
  file <- readLines(r_file)
  flag <- file %>% str_detect("system")
  if(length(flag) > 0) { print("Contains suspicious code") }
  }
```

But I wonder if there's a (much) better way?

#### Note

- One quick way of reducing risk is to use a CRAN version of the package where possible, but obviously this is not always helpful (as many packages only exist outside of CRAN)

Comment: Why not just ask about the particular package that interests you?  (Probably not on stackoverflow, but maybe on an R help list, or a subject specific list for the package.)  Or run the same tests as CRAN, and use the same rejection rules as they do:  but that will likely make you reject every one of those packages:  most of them are not on CRAN because they do dangerous things and CRAN won't accept them.)

Comment: @user2554330 I would ask about a specific package but I am much more interested in a solution that can be used over and over. As for CRAN, I think their tests involve humans looking over the code, which makes sense at scale but not for my case (I can't look over every line of code in each github repository)

Comment: CRAN relies on automated tests to put packages online.  A malicious actor could slip through their tests, but would hopefully be found reasonably quickly when users were affected.

Comment: @user2554330 how comprehensive are the cran tests? (are they the same ones as with ‘R CMD check —as-cran’ ?

Comment: Yes, very close to that.